Steam punk nuclear reactor
How do I build a steam punk nuclear reactor? I don't have any fissile material, I'm just curious about the specs.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Pile up uranium bricks inside a huge kettle boiler lined with lead. Fill it with water, then slide graphite sheets between the uranium bricks. Capture the steam as it tries to escape. Run screaming when you get the calculations wrong and it turns into a run-away nuclear reaction and the uranium burns through the floor.

...and this is why you do build a non-steampunk computerized system to do the complex implementation of complex calculations for you, and do not "eyeball it."

@controlgroup, the mystique of steampunk often relies upon ignoring the inconvenient bits of physics. The clacks in The Difference engine are likely impossible, even given modern metallurgy. IBM built one of Babbage's contraptions, but the additive effect of the clearances between the gears meant it couldn't be scaled up. Such lack of precision is easily overlooked by readers, but it can make for some good drama. To your point, yes, I think we've figured out how to build a safe nuclear reactor.
